# SFML crashes after compiling using Xcode 11 and macOS Catalina (zsh)

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, sfml

I'm simply trying to run the example SFML program in Xcode. I got it to compile but it doesn't run. It immediately crashes and prints this to the console:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/sfml-system.framework/Versions/2.5.1/sfml-system
  Referenced from: /Users/fabiosuarez/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Minesweeper-akxearyxdvvgahfbqsxchcqyauxw/Build/Products/Debug/Minesweeper.app/Contents/MacOS/Minesweeper
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Frameworks/sfml-system.framework/Versions/2.5.1/sfml-system: code signature in (/Library/Frameworks/sfml-system.framework/Versions/2.5.1/sfml-system) not valid for use in process using Library Validation: mapped file has no cdhash, completely unsigned? Code has to be at least ad-hoc signed.
```

Environment:

> - IDE: Xcode 11.2.1
> - OS: macOS Catalina 10.15.1
> - Shell: zsh 5.7.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin19.0)

Note: This is for a project where we have to make Minesweepeer so the name of the Xcode project is 'Minesweeper' but all the code is the default SFML app code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "using Library Validation" here is the vital clue. You need to [disable that using the "Disable Library Validation" entitlement](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_security_cs_disable-library-validation)

Comment: Thank you so much! Yeah it seemed to be a problem with my privacy settings, I had to accept all the frameworks one by one which was exhausting but I got it to work. Thanks again!